# PGP public key is visible

Tags: pgp, key

I have found a page with lots of PGP public keys. There is an email address on url.

This page is:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=bdS9
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Is it a vulnerability?

Comment: Think about the meaning of the word "public" and then consider what you're asking here.

Comment: Here's bof.nl's response: https://twitter.com/bitsoffreedom/status/1029467412956098560 ;-)

Comment: @user183535 It is a friendly place to ask questions and no one is mad at you. Unfortunately, the question started out with poor formatting. Combined with it being a simple question may have lead to people downvoting it. Don't take it personally!

Comment: One people just shared it to Twitter. They making jokes of me. :-)  But I know there are still good peoples like you and @Joe M thanks for being friendly. :-)

Comment: I don't think they were the one who shared it on twitter, they just posted a response from someone else who tweeted it. Some people may be joking about it, but believe me, we are not _mad_!

Comment: @user183535 The twitter account is from the very server you found the public keys.

Answer (score 12):

Public keys are intended to be published. The corresponding private key is the secure part that should not be published.

The purpose of a public key is twofold:

- It is something anyone can use to encrypt a message that only the holder of the private key should be able to read (message encryption).
- It is something that can be used to verify a message sent by the holder of the private key (message signing and verification).

Somebody wishing to communicate via public/private keys would publish their public key in a place that they control so that other people can use it when communicating with that person.

Answer (score 4):

No, that is the point of a public key.

If they were private keys it would be a problem. Check this page out for more info: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-does-pretty-good-privacy-work-3f5f75ecea97